# How to compare a Hash Key with an Integer in rails

Tags: ruby

```
params[:mg_question_id].each do |question|

    @poll=MgPollData.new

    @poll.mg_question_id= question

    params[:options_id].each do |k,v|

        if k==question
            @poll.answer= v
        end

    end

    @poll_answers.save

end
```

here, I'm comparing the array value with the hash key. But hash key is string and array is integer - that's why I'm unable to compare the both.

Is  there any solution regarding this?

Comment: If you are using a string (number value) as your hash key, then you can use **key.to_i** to convert your key to an integer value.

Comment: ya...thats correct. I thought array values are integers only .  So i didnt convert them to integers .Thats the mistake i did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to call :to_i on question.

```
params[:mg_question_id].each do |question_id|

   @poll=MgPollData.build(:mg_question_id => question_id.to_i)

   params[:options_id].each do |k,v|

      if k.to_i==question_id.to_i
        @poll.answer= v
      end

   end

   @poll_answers.save
```

end

Answer (score 1):

As others suggest you can call .to_i on question

```
  params[:mg_question_id].each do |question_id|

   @poll=MgPollData.build(:mg_question_id => question_id.to_i)

   params[:options_id].each do |k,v|

      if k.to_i==question_id.to_i
        @poll.answer= v
      end

   end

   @poll_answers.save
```

However, it's important to remember that arrays are index based beginning with 0. While hashes are object based, and hash keys are often symbols. `key: "Value"`,  and if the key is a symbol eg, `:key` calling `.to_i` may throw an error or in earlier ruby versions have unexpected side effects such as:

Returns an integer that is unique for each symbol within a particular execution of a program. Similar to `object_id`

```
:fred.to_i           #=> 9809
```

For that reason, I might call `.to_s` rather than `.to_i` opting to have them both be strings and avoid the problems with converting symbols to integers.

Hope this helps some...

Comment: Thanks @Tyler  . It's really making sense

Comment: Glad you found it useful, Best of luck on your project!